# Value not being returned

Tags: python-3.x, return

being new to this I am probably doing something silly somewhere which is breaking the code. Have taken a look at some similar posts but found nothing that helps.

So, the issue I am having is when I attempt to print newmarbles at the end it is saying it is not defined. I assume I am doing something wrong in terms of returning the value? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import random

def playNovice(marbles):
    aimove = random.randint(1, (marbles/2))
    print("AI Move", aimove)
    newmarbles = marbles - aimove
    return newmarbles

def userPlay(marbles):
    usermove = int(input("Enter your move: "))
    while usermove > marbles / 2 or usermove == 0:
        print("Invalid Move")
        usermove = int(input("Enter your move: "))
    else:
        newmarbles = marbles - usermove
        return newmarbles


difficulty = input("Which difficulty? novice or expert: ")
marbles = 100
playNovice(marbles)
userPlay(marbles)
print(newmarbles)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of `newmarbles` is local to `playNovice()`. You should assign the returned value to a variable, which may have the same name:

```
newmarbles = playNovice(marbles)
userPlay(marbles)
print(newmarbles)
```

Answer (score 1):

Return statements don't return a variable, they return a value.

`playNovice(marbles)` will return the value of `newmarbles` and then do nothing with it, what you want is to do something like

```
int aVariable = playNovice(marbles);
print(aVariable);
```

This will assign the return value of the method `playNovice` to the variable `aVariable`.